# Titanium AudioPlayer access iOS remote controls

Tags: ios, titanium

I have a AudioPlayer playing music from an url.

```
var streamer = Ti.Media.createAudioPlayer({
    url : '8..'
});
```

and then I have fixed so that I can play music in background for iOS. But the problem is that I can´t access the system buttons, for example if you lock your iPhone and press the home button twice you will get a backward, pause/play and forward button and if your iPhone is unlocked and you press the home button twice and swipe the bottom bar to the right you have system controls.

I saw a comment in a thread at appcelerators q/a:
Check the comment from Dustin Hume
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/47291/background-audio-in-14

I did all those steps and was able to run my AudioPlater but I were not be able to use the remote buttons. I have checked the API documentation and it does not say anything about this. Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using this module:
https://github.com/hoyo/TiRemoteControl

Answer (score 0):

A year ago I tried to accomplish the same thing. But as I was new to Titanium and app development in general I found a module on Titaniums marketplace that did just that thing.

https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/5573?1192373639